# Async Await issues with NodeJS & AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, async-await, aws-lambda

I'm currently developing a Lamba function call for my AWS project, but with me not being a master at asynchronous functions it appears it's falling apart, the code I've put together is:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const game = require('game-api');
const uuid = require("uuid");

AWS.config.update({
  region: "us-east-1"
});

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

    //set db
    var documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()

    //params
    const params = {
        Item: {
            'id': uuid.v1(),
            'player_1_name': null,
            'player_1_network': null,
            'player_1_matches': 0,
            'player_1_kills': 0,
            'player_1_last_updated': 0,
            'player_2_name': null,
            'player_2_network': null,
            'player_2_matches': 0,
            'player_2_kills': 0,
            'player_2_last_updated': 0,
            'match_id': 0,
            'status': 0
        },
        TableName : 'matches'
    };

    var matchData = JSON.parse(event.body);

    //player 1
    const player_1_name = matchData.player_1_name ? matchData.player_1_name : null;
    const player_1_network = matchData.player_1_network ? matchData.player_1_network : null;

    //player 2
    const player_2_name = matchData.player_2_name ? matchData.player_2_name : null;
    const player_2_network = matchData.player_2_network ? matchData.player_2_network : null;

    //match data
    const match_id = matchData.match_id ? matchData.match_id : 0;

    //game object
    let gameAPI = new game(
        [
            "email@email.com",
            "password"
        ]
    );

    //gameAPI.login() returns a Promise()
    await gameAPI.login().then(() => {

        //check stats for player 1, getStats returns a Promise()
        gameAPI.getStats(player_1_name, player_1_network).then(stats => {

            params.Item.player_1_matches = stats.lifetimeStats.matches;
            params.Item.player_1_kills = stats.lifetimeStats.kills;

        }).catch(err => {

            //error! we must work out what to do here!
            console.log(err);

        });

        //example insert
        documentClient.put(params, function(err, data){
            return callback(err, data);
        });

    }).catch(err => {
        console.log("We failed to login!");
        console.log(err);
    });

};
```

This logic seems flawed since nothing is being thrown to my AWS logs? my idea is to send the request to the function & have it do it as quickly as possible so I can send a 200 response back to Lambda, can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `async/await` you don't need to use `callback` neither you need to fall into the Promise Hell.

Just `await` on your promises and grab the result. The great advantage here is it looks as though your code is synchronous.

Here's your refactored code:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const game = require('game-api');
const uuid = require("uuid");

AWS.config.update({
  region: "us-east-1"
});

exports.handler = async (event) => {

    //set db
    var documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()

    //params
    const params = {
        Item: {
            'id': uuid.v1(),
            'player_1_name': null,
            'player_1_network': null,
            'player_1_matches': 0,
            'player_1_kills': 0,
            'player_1_last_updated': 0,
            'player_2_name': null,
            'player_2_network': null,
            'player_2_matches': 0,
            'player_2_kills': 0,
            'player_2_last_updated': 0,
            'match_id': 0,
            'status': 0
        },
        TableName : 'matches'
    };

    var matchData = JSON.parse(event.body);

    //player 1
    const player_1_name = matchData.player_1_name ? matchData.player_1_name : null;
    const player_1_network = matchData.player_1_network ? matchData.player_1_network : null;

    //player 2
    const player_2_name = matchData.player_2_name ? matchData.player_2_name : null;
    const player_2_network = matchData.player_2_network ? matchData.player_2_network : null;

    //match data
    const match_id = matchData.match_id ? matchData.match_id : 0;

    //game object
    let gameAPI = new game(
        [
            "email@email.com",
            "password"
        ]
    );

    //gameAPI.login() returns a Promise()
    await gameAPI.login()

    const stats = await gameAPI.getStats(player_1_name, player_1_network)
    params.Item.player_1_matches = stats.lifetimeStats.matches;
    params.Item.player_1_kills = stats.lifetimeStats.kills;

        //example insert
    await documentClient.put(params).promise();

};
```

If you need to handle the exceptions (you should) just wrap your await calls in `try/catch` blocks, like this:

```
try {
   console.log(await somePromise)
} catch (e) {
   console.log(e)
}
```

The snippet above is equivalent to:

```
somePromise.then(console.log).catch(console.log)
```

with the great difference that you don't need to chain promises/asynchronous code in order to keep the execution order, so I highly recommend you pick the `async/await` approach and forget about `.then().catch()`

Comment: Now it appears to be throwing errors from the `var matchData = JSON.parse(event.body);` line & `event` appears to be empty

Comment: How are you testing it?

Comment: I'm using both postman & direct AWS testing module; prior to these changes `matchData` was a valid object

Comment: If you're testing from AWS's console, you'll have to mock API's gateway event. Just go to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-on-demand-https.html, copy that JSON, modify it accordingly and use that to test it.

Comment: I am sure that's not because of this. If you check your code and mine, they're the same until that line is hit. If you're not sure what is coming inside your event object, just console.log(JSON.stringify(event)) on the first line of your handler and analyse it on CloudWatch Logs

Comment: Turns out I had to change the way my asyncs worked since it was attempting to insert empty data into my DB, but yeah; looking at your answer helped me understand what I was doing wrong! thanks